# Best LCD for mass production

Tags: surface-mount, manufacturing, through-hole, production

I'm designing a PCB that will be manufactured in small batches (a few hundreds). It will have a segment LCD with electronic components under it. I cannot choose between two form factors - with SMD pins on both sides or through-hole pins on one side:
[image]

[image]

The THT version probably will be harder to align properly because it sits on uneven surface (components with different height). In case of SMD I'm concerned about broken traces due to mechanical fatigue. Which version do you think is better? What potential problems did I miss and how can I alleviate them?

Comment: Why would generate mechanical fatigure?  Is there a lot of vibration?

Comment: The display is exposed to the user, and some users like to poke the display too much. And there's no space (and budget) for a display cover.

Comment: But again, it's just my projection of possible problems which may not be true, I want to hear about other people's experience and opinions.

Comment: I'd say the THT one is just as prone to fatigue if the user pokes on it a lot, as SMD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the device is exposed to user-finger-poking (per comments), then use the one which is mounted at both ends.  One that is mounted along one side will flex.